# Readable Store, delayed "set"

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-store

Is there a way to define a readable store, with its `set` function, however delay the calling of that function until certain criteria is met?

I'm thinking of using them for API calls, however I want to decide when to call the the set function, which would then fetch the data and populate the store with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store contract for readable stores is simply a `subscribe` function; you can arbitrarily extend the store with additional properties and methods. You could e.g. add an update function that internally uses `set`:

```js
import { readable } from 'svelte/store';

export function apiStore() {
    const store = readable(null, set => {
        store.update = () => set(new Date());
    });

    return store;
}
```

Usage:

```html
<script>
    import { apiStore } from './stores';
    const store = apiStore();
</script>
<button on:click={() => store.update()}>Update</button>
<pre>{$store}</pre>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/580f2b2b742b4d54a01b533c8a7c8a57?version=3.52.0)

If you want it to update fully automatically, you should use a `derived` store instead. They update whenever a store they depend upon changes.

Comment: Is there a difference or advantage of doing this to setting up a custom store based on a writable without `set` exposed but only the custom method using it?

Comment: @Corrl: Not really, every store other than `writable` uses `writable` internally. The only difference I could think of would be that `set` is more aggressively scoped.

Comment: What does 'more aggressively scoped' mean?

Comment: @Corrl: It is never exposed as part of the store's properties and just exists inside the initializer function. Hence its scope is as small as it can possibly be.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `readable` store would be a [custom store](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-stores) that doesn't expose `set` but instead the method that initializes the store when needed via `store.init()`

```js
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

    function createStore() {
        const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(null);

        return {
            subscribe,
            init() {
                // fetch data
                set(data)
            }
        }
    }

    export const store = createStore();
```